# Duality in robust optimization

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, duality-theorems

I only know that:

- for an LP standard primal $\left\{\begin{matrix}
  \underset{x}{\operatorname{max}}[c^Tx]\\ 
  Ax \leq b\\ 
  x \geq 0
  \end{matrix}\right.$ corresponds the LP dual $\left\{\begin{matrix}
  \underset{y}{\operatorname{min}}[b^Ty]\\ 
  A^Ty \geq c\\ 
  y \geq 0
  \end{matrix}\right.$;
- strong LP duality states that, if the primal admits optimal solution $x$, dual admits optimal solution $y$ and results $c^Tx=b^Ty$. And similarly, weak LP duality states $c^Tx \leq b^Ty$.

Unfortunately, as explained [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.02634.pdf) at page 4, to pass from (3) to (6) we need to use respectively conic and Fenchel's duality. I don't know anything about that, with many thanks to my professor, so I can't figure out this proof.

Could you help me? Every link is also welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

you can write
$(a + P\zeta )^T x \le d, \quad \forall \zeta \in Z$
as
$a^T x + (P\zeta )^T x \le d, \quad \forall \zeta \in Z$
Since this must hold for any $\zeta \in Z$, it also holds for the max of $\zeta$ in $Z$. Hence (4).
Then take the dual of the max problem (you know how to do this, use your first message). Hence (5).
They then say: we want $min_{w \in W} f(w) \le p$, that is there must exist $\bar{w} \in W$ such that $f(\bar{w}) \le p$.

So nothing fancy :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, things seem more complicated since the authors say that *"we need conic duality instead of LP duality in Step 2 [...].  Similarly [...] we need Fenchel duality in Step 2. Notice that each RC constraint has a positive safeguard in the constraint left-hand
side, e.g., $\left \| P^Tx \right \|_1,\left \| P^Tx \right \|_2$ and $q^Tw$"*.